# Visual Studio Command Prmpt hang on launch

Tags: windows-7, command-line, visual-studio

I am getting fairly frequent hangs when inlaunch the visual studio command prompt on. The only thing that the VS prompt does that differs from the normal cod prompt is to launch a batch file that sets some environment variables and adds some folders to my Path.

When it hangs, the console window appears, but it is never usable, and I have to kill it in task manager.

Any idea where I might go looking for a solution?

Comment: Run ProcMon in background and look which operations fail and compare this to a normal CMD.exe run: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: You can add an `echo on` to the beginning of the batch file (or remove or comment-out the `echo off` it may start with) and be able to see what it's doing in order to pin-point the problem.

Comment: Have you tried manually running that same batch-file from a command-prompt you open yourself?

Comment: I've tried both manually running and the process monitor thing.  The real downer is that it doesn't happen every time, so (of course) I haven't been able to get a repro when I am monitoring/testing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. It turned out it was Avast Antivirus running the console in "Deep Screen" mode, which opens a second command prompt in "Deep Screen" and the original command prompt is then left hanging. If you are running Avast, go to "Settings" -> "Antivirus" and then untick "Enable Deep Screen". If you're not running Avast, it's worthwhile checking whether your antivirus software has a similar tool.

Comment: That's a cool find.  Our company uses Webroot -- I couldn't find any settings that look similar, but I will keep looking.  In the meanwhile, I was issued a different machine, and I don't seem to have the problem anymore.  Go figure.